# Spring Redis TLS version

Tags: spring-boot, redis

Is there any property in Spring Boot that could be used for setting allowed version of TLS for Redis?
I have found properties for host and password `spring.redis.host=${HOST} spring.redis.password=${PASSWORD}` and I'd like a way to set minimum allowed version of TLS to 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such configuration property in Spring, but there is one in Java itself. You can use

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

The value of the property should be a comma-delimited list of allowed protocols. All other protocols are disabled.

I created a [very simple project](https://github.com/osvetlik/java-ssl-protocol-selection-demo) for you to demonstrate.

Here is the traffic with the server without any configuration:
[image: Communication without protocol restrictions]

Here is the traffic when running with only the TLSv1.2 enabled:
[image: Communication with protocol restrictions]

Beware! [Java versions from 12 to 14 do not respect](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239594) this property!

There are [more options how to configure this behavior](https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html).

Comment: thank you, i think this should do the thing